# Chrome: How to refresh tab if open, otherwise open new tab?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, command-line-arguments

I'm opening a .pdf file from the command line in Chrome (Windows 7 64 bit). Every time the pdf file changes open the pdf to view it, but I don't want Chrome to open it in a new tab every time.

Is there a command line argument I can use to stop a file opening in multiple tabs?

Comment: You might want to consider using  [`chromi`](https://github.com/smblott-github/chromi) possibly with its command line tool [`chromix`](https://github.com/smblott-github/chromix) which can tell Chrome to create new tabs and reload existing tabs.

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite old, but: 
The correct answer to your exact question is simply "no."   There is no command line argument you can use to stop a file opening again in a separate tab.  This is because

The best list (for readability and updates) of command line switches for Chrome that I know of is maintained [by Peter Beverloo](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) You can search through yourself to confirm my answer, of course.

If anyone is still dealing with this issue, you'll likely want to look at installing (or making) a simple extension for this.  If you want to make your own, start with [Google's documentation on the tab interaction API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs).